# TypeError - o.ngOnDestroy is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When building my angular app for production (ng serve no problem) I am getting the following error when loading one of the children modules:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: o.ngOnDestroy is not a function
TypeError: o.ngOnDestroy is not a function
    at Fi (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9573)
    at Mi (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9541)
    at Ri (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9531)
    at fo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10593)
    at go (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10719)
    at vo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10662)
    at fo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10591)
    at go (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10719)
    at mo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10641)
    at fo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10592)
    at Fi (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9573)
    at Mi (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9541)
    at Ri (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:9531)
    at fo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10593)
    at go (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10719)
    at vo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10662)
    at fo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10591)
    at go (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10719)
    at mo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10641)
    at fo (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:10592)
    at P (zone.js:814)
    at P (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at e.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3815)
    at e.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at t.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at d (zone.js:595)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at k (zone.js:1540)
```

I am using angular & angular cli 6.1.2. Any ideas what might be leading to this?

Below are the two code snippets where ngOnDestroy is found in the generated main.js file:

```
var pi = function () {
  function t(t, e, n, r) {
    this._moduleType = t, this._parent = e, this._bootstrapComponents = n, this._def = r, this._destroyListeners = [], this._destroyed = !1, this.injector = this, function (t) {
      for (var e = t._def, n = t._providers = new Array(e.providers.length), r = 0; r < e.providers.length; r++) {
        var i = e.providers[r];
        4096 & i.flags || void 0 === n[r] && (n[r] = qr(t, i))
      }
    }(this)
  }

  return t.prototype.get = function (t, e, n) {
    void 0 === e && (e = D.THROW_IF_NOT_FOUND), void 0 === n && (n = 0);
    var r = 0;
    return 4 & n ? r |= 1 : 2 & n && (r |= 4), Hr(this, {token: t, tokenKey: $n(t), flags: r}, e)
  }, Object.defineProperty(t.prototype, "instance", {
    get: function () {
      return this.get(this._moduleType)
    }, enumerable: !0, configurable: !0
  }), Object.defineProperty(t.prototype, "componentFactoryResolver", {
    get: function () {
      return this.get(Bt)
    }, enumerable: !0, configurable: !0
  }), t.prototype.destroy = function () {
    if (this._destroyed)throw new Error("The ng module " + k(this.instance.constructor) + " has already been destroyed.");
    this._destroyed = !0, function (t, e) {
      for (var n = t._def, r = new Set, i = 0; i < n.providers.length; i++)if (131072 & n.providers[i].flags) {
        var o = t._providers[i];
        if (o && o !== Fr) {
          var a = o.ngOnDestroy;
          "function" != typeof a || r.has(o) || (a.apply(o), r.add(o))
        }
      }
    }(this), this._destroyListeners.forEach(function (t) {
      return t()
    })
  }, t.prototype.onDestroy = function (t) {
    this._destroyListeners.push(t)
  }, t
}(), fi = $n(function () {
}), di = $n(ke), yi = $n(Oe), mi = $n(Ae), vi = $n(je), gi = $n(Pe), _i = $n(D), bi = $n(P);
```

and

```
function Fi(t, e, n, r) {
  var i = Hn(t, e);
  if (i) {
    var o = i.instance;
    o && (Gn.setCurrentNode(t, e), 1048576 & n && Bn(t, 512, r) && o.ngAfterContentInit(), 2097152 & n && o.ngAfterContentChecked(), 4194304 & n && Bn(t, 768, r) && o.ngAfterViewInit(), 8388608 & n && o.ngAfterViewChecked(), 131072 & n && o.ngOnDestroy())
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you manually calling `ngOnDestroy` anywhere?

Comment: Nope, that was the first thing I looked for...

Comment: its seems like something calling this, are you using any extensions ? any libraries ? please edit your question with more information.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue. `ng serve` works fine. When I build and serve through ngnix, it works. When I build and deploy to azure, it fails. I would agree  that maybe you should provide some additional details. I may work on a stackblitz example or something for my issue if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @Adrian my resolution was a clean install of npm modules

Comment: @pcnate that did not do it for me. See my "temporary" solution

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue however it is only present at runtime in production. Looks to be specific to `--prod` mode and maybe MatDialog

Comment: @pcnate Did you ever get a stackblitz put together by any chance?

Comment: The project is hard to set up on stackblitz, but it is open source: https://github.com/Codingpedia/codingmarks.org/tree/feature/pwa-support

Comment: @mwilson no, I solved my issue by reinstalling `node_modules`. I suggest checking your dependencies. One may be getting mangled too badly during build. I checked that I was importing onDestroy and implementing it as well before discovering that

Comment: Wierd. I'm getting this only in production and our build agent does all that (which guarantees a fresh install every time). I

Comment: Day 2 of pounding my head on this one. I've narrowed it down to the Angular Material Table. I only have two routes that are throwing this exception and after lots and lots of debugging, If I kill the MatTable from both components, it works as expected without the error. My current workaround is to use the `build-optimizer=false` but that is obviously undesirable. As a helpful hint for others (for debugging angular in prod), if you append `--source-map` to your prod build command, you can at least set breakpoints and actually step through the code.

Comment: Throwing in the towl and settling on turning the build-optimizer off. One thing I did notice is that if I were to run the exact build command locally and then upload my dist folder manually, no error would occur. If I let the build run as normal (we use VSTS CI) then the error would appear. Both scenarios matched up identically as far as files go with the exception of the main.js bundle. I did a diff on that between local/VSTS build and it was different. I have no idea why though so I'm giving up.

Comment: I should note that our build process doesn't have any 'extra tasks' at all. It's simply running the same `ng build --prod --aot` command.

Comment: For what it's worth, I upgraded to Angular 7 and this issue is resolved (at least I'm not getting it anymore). I was able to remove the `build-optimizer=false` (which narrows down my dist package by about 1mb).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution for the issue was to run the build process without the **build-optimizer**. Either force the flag to false:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false
```

or in angular.json set it to false in the configurations section:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
    "serviceWorker": true
  }
```

Problem is fixed with Angular 7

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after update on angluar version 6.1.10.

I fixed it like this:

1) I updated my 3rd part lib (angular-calendar)
2) deleted node_modules directory (this was **important**)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, and I just want you to know, that it was a problem an import that I had for that particular module, that was causing that. In this case, it was NgBootstrap, running with Material, I took the NgbModule out and, voila. I'm not sure about what you are doing in particular, but check your imports.