# Angular 6, AOT-compiled version throws TypeError: o.ngOnDestroy is not a function only when hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I have an Angular 6 application which works normally on almost all environments:

- Using `ng serve`
- Compiled with `ng build --aot --prod` and hosted locally using `http-server`
- Compiled with `ng build --aot --prod` and hosted on a remote server by Apache

Now I have an issue **only when hosted and served from an S3 bucket**: When navigating around the app, hitting one certain path and then trying to get back to another path, I get the following exception:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: o.ngOnDestroy is not a function
TypeError: o.ngOnDestroy is not a function
    at Pl (core.js:9510)
    at Sl (core.js:9478)
    at kl (core.js:9468)
    at ra (core.js:10525)
    at sa (core.js:10651)
    at aa (core.js:10594)
    at ra (core.js:10523)
    at sa (core.js:10651)
    at la (core.js:10573)
    at ra (core.js:10524)
    at Pl (core.js:9510)
    at Sl (core.js:9478)
    at kl (core.js:9468)
    at ra (core.js:10525)
    at sa (core.js:10651)
    at aa (core.js:10594)
    at ra (core.js:10523)
    at sa (core.js:10651)
    at la (core.js:10573)
    at ra (core.js:10524)
    at P (zone.js:814)
    at P (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at e.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3803)
    at e.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at t.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at d (zone.js:595)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at k (zone.js:1540)
```

There are no networking errors, all assets are loaded just the same as when locally hosted and Apache-hosted.

I tried to get to a human-readable stack trace by enabling source map generation in `angular.json`, but had no success with that either.

Does anyone here have an idea how the S3 hosting can impact my Angular application in this way?

**Update**: As the question came up in the comments, here's the actual (and very primitive) code of the component I am navigating away from. There is nothing in there that should cause that behavior as far as I can see:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Update 2**: I am using Angular 6.0.7.

**Update 3**: This question was flagged as a potential duplicate: [TypeError - o.ngOnDestroy is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811858). I don't think that is the case. In the linked question, the user has the problem **every time they build and open the application**. I only have the issue on a **certain hosting environment**.

Comment: I don't think its a problem with the hosting, what version of Angular are you using? and can you share the component code that you try to navigate away from(the one having the OnDestroy extension)?

Comment: I am compiling the code once, zip up the `dist` folder and upload its contents once to S3 and once to an Apache-hosted version. So the contents that should be served should be exactly the same. The component I am trying to navigate away from does neither implement `OnDestroy`, nor does it have an `ngOnDestroy` method. I added the code to my original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError - o.ngOnDestroy is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811858/typeerror-o-ngondestroy-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I have seen that question before posting my own and I don't think this is a duplicate. The user of the given question gets the problem any time she/he is building. I only get it when deploying the exact same code to a certain environment.

Comment: have you tried that solution? give it a try and let me know. and you can remove the --aot flag. its by default.

Comment: Yes, I have. It changes nothing.

Comment: can you send the URL of the application?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it's not public. I will try to build a PoC to replicate the error.

Comment: I am having the EXACT same issue (but on Azure). Another activish article on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811858/typeerror-o-ngondestroy-is-not-a-function